# Eclipse Mars Not Running After Software Update

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-15.04

I am running Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu 15.04. It has been running fine for months. I did a typical software update on Eclipse yesterday and it has not started since. It runs the splash screen and then quits. When I try to run Eclipse from the command line, it reverts to an older version (3.8). Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: What error messages are you getting, if any? Do you have multiple versions of Eclipse installed? Maybe the installer didn't clear out the previous version, and it's trying to launch that instead?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while ago. I fixed it by downloading a new eclipse archive from the main eclipse site (http://www.eclipse.org/) and using eclipse from there. The eclipse installation that can be installed by default from the Software Center of Ubuntu does not like to get updated I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to uninstall and reinstall the whole thing, including plug-ins.  This seemed to work.